# How to send two parameter id and name in onclick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

Here I have many users(with id,name,role defined) in html. When I click in one of the user It displays the modal and inside this modal I want to display the id,name and role of that user. I am only being able to dispaly id. How can I display name and role also ?

html

```
   {% for user in users %}
         <li>
           <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>{{ user.name }}, {{user.role}}
            <a href="" class="text-primary" onclick = "send_message({{user.id}} )">Message</a>
          </li>
   {% endfor %}
```

script

```
function send_message(id){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#sendmessage').modal('show');
  $('#send_message_modal_title').text("Send Message to User");
  $('#sendmessage').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#user_id").val(id);
    $("#user_name").val(name, role);
    
  })
```

modal

```
<input name="cleaner" id="user_id">
 <input type="text" value="name and role" class="form-control">  #how to display name and role ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can simply pass name and role to the send_message function as follows:

```
{% for user in users %}
         <li>
           <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>{{ user.name }}, {{user.role}}
            <a href="" class="text-primary" onclick = "send_message({{user.id}}, '{{ user.name }}', '{{user.role}}'  )">Message</a>
          </li>
{% endfor %}
```

And access it here:

```
function send_message(id, name, role){
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#sendmessage').modal('show');
  $('#send_message_modal_title').text("Send Message to User");
  $('#sendmessage').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#user_id").val(id);
    $("#user_name").val(`${name} ${role}`);
  })
}
```

If you are using JavaScript for click functionality. Try the following: Supposing anchor tag has a class name of show

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // User array of objects
        var users = [{id:1, name: "Shubham", role: "admin"}, {id:2, name: "Robert", role: "admin"}];

        // Add event listener
        buttons  = document.querySelectorAll(".show");
        index = 0;
        for(let button of buttons) {
            button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
                send_message(users[index++])
            })
        }

        // get user here
        function send_message(user) {
            console.log(user);
        }
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719039/being-unable-to-pass-more-than-two-parameters-in-onclick-function I tried your solution but I got this problem here . Can you help there ?

Comment: It will definitely work, just make sure to add single quotes (' ') around passing variables so that javascript's send_message function could treat them as an input parameter. Otherwise, it will give an error like something is not defined as it will treat it as a variable instead of an input string.

Comment: I tried passing single quotes also but didn't worked

Comment: What is the actual error you are getting? let me know.

Comment: I am getting `Uncaught ReferenceError`

Comment: after removing the single quote the error goes but in the function I get value as undefined

Comment: So what do you get other than uncaught reference error, when allowing single quote

Comment: `jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: get_details is not defined
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> ((index):1108)
    at l (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)`

Comment: This is some other error. You didn't provide the get_detail function here.

Comment: this is inside the get_detail function. If I only changed to signle quote it throws this error if not error goes. The strange thing is if I only pass one or two paramters from onclick then it displays the right value from thr function but if I pass more than 2 parameter it displays undefined to the added paramter(first 2 parameter works)

Comment: Let me clarify, you are using for in python to iterate through users or using javascript? If using JavaScript as done here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719039/being-unable-to-pass-more-than-two-parameters-in-onclick-function) then  you need to bind each button with event listener separately.

Comment: It is only javascript now. How to bind it then ?

Comment: please post the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63719039/being-unable-to-pass-more-than-two-parameters-in-onclick-function

Answer (score 1):

First thing would be to [avoid inline handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045), they have way too many problems to be worth using nowadays, especially escaping issues (which you'll run into here). Attach event listeners properly using Javascript with `addEventListener` or jQuery instead. You can tie the data to the element with data attributes:

```
<li>
  <i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i>{{ user.name }}, {{user.role}}
  <a href="" class="text-primary" data-id="{{user.id}}" data-name="{{user.name}}" data-role="{{user.role}}">Message</a>
</li>
```

and

```
$('.text-primary').on('click', (e) => {
  const { id, name, role } = e.target.dataset;
  // attach id, name, and role to modal as desired
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simply send user object as parameter

html

```
... onclick="send_message({{user}})" ...
```

script

```
function send_message(user){
    var id = user.id;
    var name = user.name;
    var role = user.role;
    ....
}
```